# Como faço para que ao clicar clicar no + mudar para - e ao clicar no - mudar para +

Tags: javascript

```js
function mostrar(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display !== "none") {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
    return;
  }
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")).forEach(
    div => (div.style.display = "none")
  );
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
        .hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="max-width:500px; margin:5 auto;">
    <div class="col-12" style="font-size:18px; font-weight:600;">Rio de Janeiro
    <span style="float:right" onClick="mostrar('mostra-1')">+</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 hidden" id="mostra-1">
    <span style="font-size:16px; color:#03bb85;;">Nome da Cidade</span><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alguma alma abençoada pra me ajudar?

Comment: As duas me atenderam amigo eu queria avaliar as duas, mas a do @Jean Barbosa, se adaptou devido ao meu código, mas muito obrigado, sou muito grato pela ajuda!

Comment: A sim é porque sou novo aqui, vou dá uma olhada! Valeuuuu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma alternativa, que considero mais simples, seria utilizar o elemento HTML [`<details>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) que cria uma caixa de divulgação no qual as informações do detalhe são visíveis apenas quando o elemento é alternado para um estado "aberto". Visualmente é estilizável, podendo se tornar similar a um Collapsible ou Acordeom, portanto dispensando a personalização em JS.

O conteúdo de `<details>` é normalmente apresentado na tela usando um acionador, um pequeno triângulo que gira para indicar o estado aberto/fechado, com um rótulo próximo ao triângulo. O conteúdo do elemento [`<summary>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/summary) é usado como rótulo.

Para atender o seu requisito de ter um acionador personalizado localizado a direita:

- `+` quando a caixa de divulgação estiver aberta.
- `-` quando a caixa de divulgação estiver fechada.

[`<summary>` suporta a propriedade list-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#customizing_the_disclosure_widget) para personalizar o acionador de `<details>`.Oculte o acionador padrão do elemento `<details>` configurando a propriedade [`list-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style) de seu respectivo `<summary>` com o valor `none`.
Use em conjunto o atributo [`open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details#attr-open) de `<details>` e o pseudo elemento [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/::after) para definir os novos acionadores.
Para posicionar o acionador ao lado direito do container use [float: right](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/float).

```css
details {
  max-width: 500px;           
  margin: 5 auto;
}

summary {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;               /*Define o ponteiro do mouse como indicador*/
  list-style: none;              /*Oculta o acionador padrão*/
}

summary::after {
  float: right;                 /*Posiciona o acionador personalizado ao lado direito do container*/
  content: "+";                 /*Quando a caixa de divulgação estiver fechada exibe +*/
}

details[open] summary::after {
  float: right;                /*Posiciona o acionador personalizado ao lado direito do container*/
  content: "-";                /*Quando a caixa de divulgação estiver aberta exibe -*/
}

details span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #03bb85;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Rio de Janeiro</summary>
  <span>Nome da Cidade</span>
</details>
```

Caso queira restringir somente ao acionador os eventos mouse é possível usar [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

```css
details {
  max-width: 500px;           
  margin: 5 auto;
}

summary {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;               
  list-style: none;              
  pointer-events: none;          /*O elemento deixa de ser alvo de eventos de mouse*/
}

summary::after {
  float: right;                 
  content: "+";                 
  pointer-events: auto;         /*Habilita o elemento a ser alvo de eventos de mouse*/
}

details[open] summary::after {
  float: right;                
  content: "-";                
  pointer-events: auto;        /*Habilita o elemento a ser alvo de eventos de mouse*/
}

details span {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #03bb85;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Rio de Janeiro</summary>
  <span>Nome da Cidade</span>
</details>
```

Comment: Augusto sabe me dizer se tem problema de compatibilidade em certos navegadores?

Comment: Havia no passado no Chrome problemas de compatibilidade do `list-style: none;` com `<summary>` mas já foram resolvidos, tanto que escrevi a resposta num Chrome.

Comment: Ótimo! Fiz os testes com alguns navegadores com o outro código que o amigo adaptou pra mim mas acabou dando bugs em alguns navegadores, o seu funcionou perfeito, então irei avaliar como melhor resposta! Obrigado amigo

Answer (score 0):

Tem vários pontos que precisam ser melhorados na estrutura do código da pergunta. Mas uma forma de alterar o *ícone*, mantendo o código atual, seria assim:

```js
function mostrar(id) {
  
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display !== "none") {
event.target.innerHTML = "+";
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
return;
  }
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")).forEach(
div => (div.style.display = "none")
  );
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("controle")).forEach(controle => (controle.innerHTML = "+"));
  event.target.innerHTML = "-";
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#controle {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="max-width:500px; margin:5 auto;">
<div class="col-12" style="font-size:18px; font-weight:600;">Rio de Janeiro
<span  class="controle" style="float:right" onClick="mostrar('mostra-1')">+</span>
</div>
<div class="col-12 hidden" id="mostra-1">
<span style="font-size:16px; color:#03bb85;;">Nome da Cidade</span><br>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="max-width:500px; margin:5 auto;">
<div class="col-12" style="font-size:18px; font-weight:600;">Rio de Janeiro
<span  class="controle" style="float:right" onClick="mostrar('mostra-2')">+</span>
</div>
<div class="col-12 hidden" id="mostra-2">
<span style="font-size:16px; color:#03bb85;;">Nome da Cidade</span><br>
</div>
</div>
```

Utilizei o seu if original e incluí as linhas de innerHTML, junto com a troca de display.

Pesquise mais sobre seleção de elementos ([exemplo01](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) e [ex02](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors)), [innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp), definições de classe e id. Ainda, veja um exemplo com o Bootstrap que pode auxiliar: [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example).

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo, funcionou perfeito, que Deus te abençoe e crie oportunidades em sua vida! Fica na paz

Comment: Amigo só observei uma coisa, está dando conflito se eu adicionar mais um código desse abaixo e mudar para mostra-2, quando clico ele muda o de cima

Comment: Modifiquei para ser possível incluir mais "mostra-".

Comment: Perfeito amigo, muito obrigado! Me salvou